# ¿Como puedo cambiar la estructura de un objecto?

Tags: javascript

Tenia un array de objetos de este tipo

```
data = [
 {id: 1, nombre: "Juan", sexo: "M"},
 {id: 2, nombre: "Carlos", sexo: "M"}, 
 {id: 3, nombre: "Juana", sexo: "F"},
 {id: 4, nombre: "Carolina", sexo: "F"}, 
 {id: 5, nombre: "Marta", sexo: "F"},
 {id: 6, nombre: "Ricardo", sexo: "M"},
 {id: 7, nombre: "Hernan", sexo: "M"}
]
```

Quería contar cuantos de sexo masculino y femenino había en dicho objeto

```
const arraySexo = data.map(x => x.sexo)
const objectSexos = arraySexo.reduce((counter, sexo) => {
  counter[sexo] = (counter[sexo] || 0) + 1;
  return counter;
  }, {});
```

El resultado de esto es este objeto:

```
const objectSexos = { F: 3, M: 4 }
```

Pero necesito que el objeto resultado sea de este tipo:

```
const objectSexos = [ {sexo: "F", count: 3}, {sexo: "M", count:4} ]
```

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Podría utilizar `map` nuevamente para construir el objeto deseado, iteramos las claves del objeto retornado por  `Object.keys` y retornamos la nueva estructura del objeto.

```
const nuevObject = Object.keys(objectSexos).map(elm => 
                      ({ 'sexo': elm, 'count': objectSexos[elm] }) );
```

```js
const data = [
 {id: 1, nombre: "Juan", sexo: "M"},
 {id: 2, nombre: "Carlos", sexo: "M"}, 
 {id: 3, nombre: "Juana", sexo: "F"},
 {id: 4, nombre: "Carolina", sexo: "F"}, 
 {id: 5, nombre: "Marta", sexo: "F"},
 {id: 6, nombre: "Ricardo", sexo: "M"},
 {id: 7, nombre: "Hernan", sexo: "M"}
]
const arraySexo = data.map(x => x.sexo)
const objectSexos = arraySexo.reduce((counter, sexo) => {
  counter[sexo] = (counter[sexo] || 0) + 1;
  return counter;
  }, {});
const nuevObject = Object.keys(objectSexos).map(elm => ({ 'sexo': elm, 'count': objectSexos[elm] }) );
console.log(nuevObject)
```